# parsing xml into listpicker

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, listpicker

i use this code to parse xml result into a listpicker control:

```
     if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        XElement xmlItems = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
        var list = new List<auth>();
        foreach (var response in xmlItems.Descendants("result"))
        {

            var nom = (string)response.Element("nom").Value;
            var id = (string)response.Element("id").Value;
            list.Add(new auth
            {
                state = nom,
                id = id,
            });


        }
        this.defaultPicker.ItemsSource = list;
        this.defaultPicker.DisplayMemberPath = "state";
        <response><status>OK</status><result><id>1</id><nom>ARIANA</nom></result><result><id>2</id><nom>BEJA</nom></result>.....</response>
```

it returns only the first item but when i click into the list it takes me to a list of path of the auth class !
any ideas please?

Comment: How your listpicker template looks like?

Comment: <toolkit:ListPicker HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,239,48,172" Width="407" x:Name="defaultPicker" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" Header="Choisir Gouvernerat :"  ItemCountThreshold="30">
            </toolkit:ListPicker>                                                                Ps:in fact it returns to me only the first item, but when i click into the listpicker it takes me to a list of path of the auth clas, an other issue, this method has worked but with 4 or 5 items in back..i don't know if the great number(24) of items this time is the problem ! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create FullModeItemTemplate with appropriate Bindings such as:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding state}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```

Comment: thanks Ku6opr, it worked but when i choose an item it doesn't appear in the listpicker like a chosen one ...in fact it appear for a second then it returns to display the first one !

Comment: Problem in another place. This code should works fine. Give me more info about how listpicker depend on another elements

Comment: ok, i made some changes this is the c#:if (e.Error != null)
return;
XElement xmlItems = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
defaultPicker.ItemsSource = from response in xmlItems.Descendants("result")
let amt = response.Element("nom")
let eb = response.Element("id")
select new auth
{
nom = amt == null ? null : amt.Value,
id = eb == null ? null : eb.Value,
};
defaultPicker.DisplayMemberPath = "nom";